# POST body is incomplete in PHP

Tags: php, apache

PHP FPM 7.4
Apache
AWS Load Blancer

Sending large payloads of around 1MB, we fetch the data like this:

$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');

This works most of time but randomily we are seeing payloads cut off. The PHP script still begins to execute and I can access the incomplete payload, but after about 100 milliseconds the script dies and a 502 is returned.

I was as able to reproduce this by creating a script to send the same post body over and over again and it failed around every 1 in 20. Instead of the payload being 1mb it was maybe 400-600k.

Most recent error from Apache logs:
[Thu Jan 11 16:54:01.566102 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17704] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 10.1.0.25:33098] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)

- Tested the payload with a POST inside the server to rule out the load balancer
- Using ignore_user_abort to try keep the script alive
- Increased EC2 instance
- Increated PHP-FPM max limits

Comment: The first thing to do is to check for errors in [the error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel). Are there any? None?

Comment: How much memory does the server have available?  Maybe it's running out of memory and the process is being killed by the os.  Are you using tcp sockets or unix sockets? Is there anything in the server error logs when you are running your test?

Comment: @gview Server has plenty of available memory and CPU. We are seeing this error: [Thu Jan 11 16:54:01.566102 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17704] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 10.1.0.25:33098] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)

Comment: Check the PHP configuration - especially https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: Are you using this module?  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html